# Powershell remoting only with domain account

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

Im trying to create a PSSESSION between two Windows 2016 servers, both in the same domain. PSremoting is enabled and Test-Wsman works fine. 
I want to enter the remote session on target machine with a local admin-account of the target machine, provided by the -credentials parameter. But it just works if I use a domain account. 
So:

```
New-PSSession Targetmachine -Credential <credentials from domain\MemberOfLocalAdminGroup>
```

works **fine**, but

```
New-PSSession Targetmachine -Credential <credentials from targetmachine\localadmin>
```

does **not**.Why?

The latter results in an error: `Connecting to remote server xxxxxxx failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x8009030e occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.`

Comment: most probably a GPO will be causing this

Answer (score 1):

Try using other authentication mechanisms — either `Basic`, `Credssp` or `Digest`:

```
New-PSSession Targetmachine -Authentication <Basic | Credssp | Digest> -Credential <credentials from targetmachine\localadmin>
```

By default `Kerberos` is used, and, since `targetmachine\localadmin` is not a domain user, — it will fail.